# Get all keywords associated with journals of interest in the last year

Tags: python

I am trying to identify current trends in Computational Biology publications. I want to access PubMed, for a list of journals and access all articles published in 2017. Next for these articles, I want to get all keywords associated with these articles.

Question: I need help modifying the code so I extract all articles published in 2017 not just the latest ones.

Loading Entrez and Medline from Biopython

```
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import Medline
Entrez.email = "my@email.com"
```

List of Journals I am interested in

```
JTList = ["Bioinformatics", "Bioinformatics and Biology Insights", "BMC Bioinformatics", "Briefings in Bioinformatics",
      "Bulletin of Mathematical Biology", "Cancer Informatics", 
      "Computational and Structural Biotechnology Journal", "Computational Biology and Chemistry", 
      "Computers in Biology and Medicine", "Current Bioinformatics", "Database", "EMBnet.journal", 
      "Evolutionary Bioinformatics", "IEEE/ACM Transactions on Computational Biology and Bioinformatics", 
      "International Journal of Functional Informatics and Personalized Medicine", 
      "Journal of Bioinformatics and Computational Biology", "Journal of Biomedical Informatics", 
      "Journal of Computational Biology", "Journal of Mathematical Biology", "Journal of Theoretical Biology", 
      "PLoS Computational Biology", "Rapid Communications in Mass Spectrometry", 
      "Source Code for Biology and Medicine", "Statistical Applications in Genetics and Molecular Biology"]
```

**This gets the latest 20 articles in one journal. I want this to fetch all articles for 2017 and for all journals in my list.

```
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term="Briefings in Bioinformatics[JOUR]")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
```

Now I get all the article IDs and extract their keywords.

```
IDList = []
for journal in JTList:
    jour = journal + "[JOUR]"
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term=jour)
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    IDList.extend(record["IdList"])

keywrds = []
for record in records:
    keywrds.extend(record.get("OT", "?"))
```

Thanks for your help. I welcome all suggestions to improve this code.

Comment: Could please improve your post? It is not clear what is *your* question.

Comment: @iled does the new modification help? I need help editing `handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term="Briefings in Bioinformatics[JOUR]")` . Right now it is accessing PubMed for just "Briefings in Bioinformatics", I want it to access for all journals in my list "JTList". Currently, it only gets the latest articles, I want it to get all articles published in 2017.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you. I actually do not have any hint for you, since I am not familiar with that package. I came here from Review.

Comment: Without knowing about the structure of `handle` and `record`, it looks like you could wrap up that code and the block below in some function. Then you can call that function multiple times providing a different journal name at a time, e.g., iterating over the entries in `JTList`. By the end you could aggregate all the resulting `keywrds` lists in any fashion that suits your needs. Does this make sense?

Comment: @iled Yes I can do that for the journals but I still need to figure out how to specify dates. Thanks I ll add that change.

Comment: Looking at documentation, this might help. Traverse through all the terms in `JTList` to search for all items in your list, and to fetch all articles for 2017 use `reldate in Entrez.esearch` specifying number of days in `reldate`.

Comment: Looking at the tutorial, It looks like `record` might have a key named `date`. Not sure if that would be the publication date.

Comment: @iled thanks for your help